# StringTokenizer struggling to print out what is between stars

Tags: java

I am trying to make by using StringTokenizer that from string like example "*star 1* wars are the best" would print out like:

```
*star 1*
wars 
are
the
best
```

It prints out like:

```
*star
1*
wars
are
the
best
```

The code:

```
String delimiters = " "; 
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiters);
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextElement();
```

Many thanks for the help

Comment: [*`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class... its use is discouraged in new code.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: because there is a space between the word star and 1.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you wind up using `StringTokenizer` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), the use of `StringTokenizer` is discouraged. You should use `split` or regexes instead.

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

This problem can be solved with regexes, which is much more powerful than a string tokeniser.

You can use this regex:

```
\*[^*]+\*|\S+
```

Which matches either of the following:

- characters enclosed in `*`, including the `*`s. (`\*[^*]+\*`).
- Non-whitespace characters (`\S+`)

Which are exactly the two things you want to print. You match the regex against the line, and print out each match.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\*[^*]+\\*|\\S+").matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```